# Using AJAX to reload part of a page from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage with a calendar that's created from PHP. I have a PHP function that creates the calendar (as a table) and returns it to the page to be inserted, like this:

```
<?php
    $calendar = new date("Y-m-d");
?>
<html>
    ...
    <?=$calendar?>
    ...
</html>
```

I have a Calendar.php file with a __toString() method that gets called when I do . That __toString() method is the method that creates the calendar

I know how to use AJAX to return the entire page but I'll like to just run the PHP function to recreate the calendar and send that to the page. Currently, we change the month by recreating it in the backend and refresh the whole page to show the new month. I don't like the refreshing so that's why I want to do AJAX (or really anything I can use to refresh a part of the page without reloading the whole page). How can I run that PHP code and send that to the page without reloading the page?

To clarify, on the page, I have a table with id="calendar". There are other things on the page but the main thing is, the calendar has arrows to navigate to the previous month and the next month. Currently, when you click on the arrows to either go to the next month or the previous month, the page is reloaded with the new month/date in the URL and our site gets the date from the query. I want to refresh the calendar with the new month using AJAX or any other way to execute the PHP code and send it to the browser, all without having to reload the entire page. I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Use AJAX you fetch the new data and manipulate the DOM with JavaScript to update the page. You can do this manually or use a single-page application (SPA) framework, e.g. Angular, React or Vue. I think, jQuery has a plugin for this, but I don't know it.

Comment: Any idea what that would look like? I'm still new to using AJAX so I'm still trying to understand it. I managed to get it to return the entire page but I'm still trying to figure out either how to get it to return part of a page or extract the part of the page I want

Comment: AJAX shouldn't return a whole `<html>` page. It should just return the `<div>` that you want to replace.

Comment: I guess, this question is too broad for Stackoverflow. You should start a tutorial on AJAX and DOM manipulation or SPA. I recommend [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) for this task.

Comment: I suppose I need to understand AJAX more. Do you suggest any particular website I can go to that'll explain it really well? I'll like to use jQuery since I really like how it looks and works in jQuery.

Comment: I wouldn't use jQuery for this. You would have to manually do all the work or use one of the outdated plugins ([jquery-tmpl](https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery-tmpl/)). Modern web development has changed. I don't know any reason to use jQuery nowadays. 2014 jQuery was great, but I haven't used for at least 5 years. Plugins for jQuery templates are 9 years old and no longer maintained.

Comment: So you suggest using JavaScript's XMLHttpRequest() instead?

Comment: Again, I recommend a framework like Vue or React. I also mentioned Angular, but that's for larger projects. Don't reinvent the wheel. `XMLHttpRequest` is also outdated. You should at least use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Ok, I'll look into both

Answer (score -1):

You can load the entire page using AJAX but its unnecessarily large amount of data.

You can just load the part you need: if there is a query string called 'calendar' or something you display only the calendar HTML.
And you make a request to '?calendar' every minute or so.

This solution is not the best because you return plain HTML data.
You could make an endpoint which returns JSON data with the calendar data and you parse it in JS.